# Random Number Between 2 Values

Tags: c++, random

Hi i wanna generate a random number between 2 values.
I have 2 variables. 
This is the default value:
(MIN = MAX = 1)

Later this value can change!

I have use this:

```
rand()%(max-min)+min;
```

But i got debug about division for zero.
Any ideas?

Edit: With the default value the number generated must be 1.

Comment: Just use a `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: Do you want C or C++ the answer will be different.

Comment: `C` is not the same as `C++`

Comment: There's no language called "C and C++", you will need to pick **exactly one** of them.

Comment: C++ sorry i have edited the post

Comment: note that () and % has *precedens* before +. so +min is evaluated **after** rand()%(max-min). and as Shafik states, modulus with 0 is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your min and max value can not be same. If it is initial guess then try having max=2 and min=1

Answer (score 7):

In your initial case `(max-min)` is `0` and modulus by zero is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). From the C++ draft standard section `5.6` *Multiplicative operators* says:

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined. [...]

As for generating a random number between `min and max` you should use the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [uniform_int_distrubution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    int min = 1, max = 1 ;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min,max);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            std::cout << dist(e2) << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

If for some reason *C++11* is not an option then the *C FAQ* gives us the proper formula when using `rand` in the section [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)  which indicates to generate random numbers in the range `[M, N]` you use the following:

> M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)

Comment: I know where is the problem so i would like a solution because i have searched allot and found nothing. Edit: With the default value the number generated must be 1.

Comment: @user2295277 added solution as well, it was not clear from your question that you were aware of the source of the issue, Regardless the explanation is useful for future readers for whom may not see it.

Answer (score 2):

The range `[min, max]` contains `max - min + 1` numbers! So your code should have been like this:

```
rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
```

Don't forget to check the value of `RAND_MAX` though, your range shouldn't get close to that. In fact, you want it to be much smaller than that to avoid too much bias.